# SQL-Server Geography Remove an overlap

Tags: sql, sql-server, polygon, geography

I'm trying to remove an overlap with the SQL-Server 2012 but i have no clue how to do it.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
[Geo] [geography] NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 0.1 0, 0.1 0.1, 0 0.1,0 0))', 4326))
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0.05 0.05, 0.15 0.05, 0.15 0.15, 0.05 0.15, 0.05 0.05 ))', 4326))
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

My idea would be to use the STIntersection() function to get the overlapping polygon and then somehow to delete it from one of the polygons.

Comment: Do you ultimately want an area that is just the union of all the areas? If so, take a look at STUnion.

Comment: No I want to remove the overlapping area from one of the polygons so that STIntersects = 0.

Comment: Take a look at STDifference then. That is, create a new geography instant defined as a.STDifference(b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, STDifference will do the trick. That is, given two geography instances a & b that may or may not have an overlap, setting a = a.STDifference(b) will remove any area from a that intersects with b.